# ¿Cómo recuperar la información de un select mediante el método POST?

Tags: php, mysql, post

quiero recuperar el dato que selecciono mediante un select y mandarlo a otro archivo php.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="autocompletar">
            <select name="empresas" style="width:1000px">
                <?php 
                    require("connect.php");
                    $sql = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM CLIE01";
                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                        echo "<option value= >".$row['NOMBRE']; 
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <center>    
                <input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-info">
            </center>
        </div>
```

Quiero recuperar el valor "empresas" y mandarlo a mi otro código.

```
<?php 
        $var = $_REQUEST['empresas'];
        echo "<p> $var </p>";
        echo "hola";
?>
```

No me marca errores, pero no me imprime el valor de "empresas"

Comment: el select debe estar en un FORM y debe haber un submit. Hecho eso puedes mirar en `$_POST["empresas"]`. con `$_REQUEST` también funciona pero request es un poco mas especial ya que mira en post, parámetros y alguna otra cosa mas.

Comment: En general recomendaría no crear la consulta en el cliente ya que es una receta para que te hackeen.

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!

Te recomiendo crear un "form" para el select, y pasar los datos por POST, utilizando un submit.

Así podría quedar el HTML:

```
<div class="autocompletar">
    <form action="archivo.php" method="POST">
        <select name="empresas" style="width:1000px">
        <option>Ejemplo</option>
        <option>Ejemplo</option>
        </select>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Consultar" class="btn btn-info"></center>
    </form>
</div>
```

Y en el archivo PHP:

```
$empresa = $_POST['empresas'];
```

Ya tienes la selección en el archivo PHP, ahora puedes hacer lo que quieras con el dato.
En general lo más recomendable es mantener el PHP y el HTML separados.

¡Espero haberte ayudado!